# How do you work with multiple models in Ember JS (without Ember Data)?

Tags: ember.js

I created a small example to try and make multiple models work without Ember Data.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('employees', function () {
        this.route('employee');
    });
});

App.Employee = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.Employee.reopenClass({
    findAll: function () {
        return $.getJSON("http://localhost/api/employee").then(
            function (response) {
                var employees = [];
                response.forEach(function (child) {
                    employees.push(App.Employee.create(child));
                });
                console.log(employees.join('\n'));
                return employees;
            }
        );
    }
});

App.EmployeesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});

App.EmployeesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Employee.findAll();
    }
});
```

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <p>Application template</p>
    {{#linkTo employees}}<button>Show employees</button>{{/linkTo}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="employees">
    <p>Employees template</p>
    {{#each controller}}
    <p>{{Name}}</p>
    {{/each}}
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

When I navigate to the `localhost/#/employee` url directly, it works perfectly fine, but when I click on the "Show employees" button, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addArrayObserver'
```

I'm probably missing something somewhere, but I'm not exactly sure which object the error is referring to right there. My model hook is being called correctly when I push the button, same as if I navigate with by manually inputting the url, so I don't understand what exactly is different in the two cases mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally got this thing working.

My error was to try to recreate (read copy-paste) [Evil Trout's example](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html) of doing an Ember application without Ember Data, and not understanding the underlying concepts well enough.

My `findAll` method was returning a Promise object although the controller expects an array, hence the `Uncaught TypeError`. What you need to do is return an empty `ArrayProxy` which will be populated once the JSON response is received.

```
App.Employee.reopenClass({
    findAll: function () {
        var employees = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({ content: [] });
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:49441/api/employee").then(
            function (response) {
                response.forEach(function (child) {
                    employees.pushObject(App.Employee.create(child));
                });
            }
        );
        return employees;
    }
});
```

If you correctly return an array with this method, you don't have to explicitly specify that the controller is an `ArrayController`.

My question is kind of silly now that I know what I did wrong, but hopefully it will help someone else getting started.