# Navigating to Record works, but deep link throws error?

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple EmberJS application with 2 simple models (ember-model). Accounts and Items, while an Account hasMany Items.

So when i navigate to #/accounts/1/items with the links in the application it works perfectly fine. However when i directly reload #/accounts/1/items i get an error:

```
Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed <App.Account:ember335> (wrapped in (generated items controller)) ember.js?body=1:382
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver' ember.js?body=1:19476
Assertion failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property change notifications. ember.js?body=1:382
```

This is how my App looks like:

```
App.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'accounts', ->
    @resource 'account', path: ':account_id', ->
      @resource 'items'

App.AccountRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.Account.find(params.account_id)

App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @.modelFor('account').get('items')

App.Account = Ember.Model.extend
  name: Ember.attr('string')
  item_ids: Ember.attr(),
  items: (->
    App.Items.find(@.get('comment_ids'))
  ).property('comment_ids')

App.Item = Ember.Model.extend
  name: Ember.attr('string')
```

Controllers are standard (empty).

In the JS console a call like this works fine and returns the correct results, even after the error is thrown (and nothing rendered):

```
 App.Account.find(1).get('items')
```

I have no idea why this is happening and the code seems so straight forward that its really annoying not to have a clue. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Not solved yet, but found a issue that seems like it has the same cause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970755/how-do-you-work-with-multiple-models-in-ember-js-without-ember-data/16037359#16037359

Comment: How does your AccountRoute look like?

Comment: added the account route to the first pos

Comment: After switching to embedded hasMany the error is gone.
Not really the solution to the issue itself (thats why i don close it), but it does the job in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I am no ember-data expert, but it seems that it is returning a promise. Therefore you should try:

```
App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(){
    var accountPromise = App.Account.find(1);
    var itemsPromise = Ember.Deferred.create();
    accountPromise.then(function(account){
      itemsPromise.resolve(account.get("items"));
    });
    return itemsPromise;
  }
});
```

**Why does it have to be it that way?**

1. `App.Account.find(1);` performs an asynchronous call and therefore returns a promise.
2. That's why you can't immediately return the items, you have to wait for accountPromise to be fulfilled.
3. You return a new promise (`itemspromise`) which gets fulfilled when the accountPromise gets fulfilled.
4. Because you return a Promise, Ember waits for it to be fulfilled and uses the result as the model for your Controller.

**PS:** Actually this seems a little bit complicated to me. I thinks this will work, but there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Seems to go in the right direction with the data i depend on not beeing ready in that moment. App.Account.find() does not return a promise however, so this did not really fix it :(
Thanks though!

Comment: Aren't you using ember-data?

Comment: Just found the answer in the docs `Otherwise, a new record will be created and put into the loading state, then returned. Feel free to use this record in templates; because everything in Ember.js is bindings-aware, templates will automatically update as soon as the record finishes loading.` http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-models/

Comment: How is App.Account defined? Is there a hasMany declaration to items?

Comment: added the model definitions at the time (skipped rest-adapter config, just the model itself).
by now i'm pretty confident it was the way i was loading the relationship as described here (http://blog.sensible.io/2013/06/26/ember-model-introduction.html) after i had problems with the relationship loading from ember-model itself

Comment: Your approach with a computed property just can't work here. You are bypassing ember-data (or ember-model) with this hack. Therefore it does not work.